# NSImage can't set name

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm taking images from the panel,assign name and putting them in to array,and after.

However I run in the issue when I taking image more than 1 time (same image), the name property is always nil

here is the code

```
            for (int i =0 ; i < [[panel URLs]count]; i++)
            {
                NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[[panel URLs]objectAtIndex:i]];
                if (image)
                {
                    NSString * fileName = [[[panel URLs]objectAtIndex:i]lastPathComponent];
                    [image setName:fileName];//Sets nil :'( when same image opened multiple times (((((

                    NSLog(@"The file name is %@",fileName);//But the filename is not will and the NSLog is good ...
                    [_imagesArray addObject:image];
                }
            }
```

According to the [`setName:` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/setName:) it seems to be normal behaviour:

> **Discussion**
>
> If the receiver is already registered under a different
>   name, this method unregisters the other name. If a different image is
>   already registered under the name specified in aString, this method
>   does nothing and returns NO.
>
> When naming an image using this method, it is convention not to
>   include filename extensions in the names you specify. That way, you
>   can easily distinguish between images you have named explicitly and
>   those you want to load from the app's bundle. For information about
>   the rules used to search for images, and for information about the
>   ownership policy of named images, see the imageNamed: method.

But even when after I do clearFunction as follows

```
- (void)clearImages
{
    _imagesArray = nil;
    [_imagesGridCollectionView setContent:_imagesArray];
    [_imagesGridCollectionView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

And after this clear Method I do pick the images I picked before
and the Names is not set ...

My Question is:

After I clear an Image how can I force the next images to take a names, and unregister the previous images ->(I don't need them because I deleted them with clear method).

EDIT:

In order to clear the names cache of NSImages

I added:

```
- (void)clearImages
{
     for(NSImage *image in _imagesArray)
     {
         [image setName:nil];
     }
    _imagesArray = nil;
    [_imagesGridCollectionView setContent:_imagesArray];
    [_imagesGridCollectionView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: so is your problem that the names are not set to what you want in the files *on disk* (since you are clearing out the `_imagesArray` from memory and then picking them from disk again later on)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No, I want to pick lets say 3 images 1.jpg 2.jpg and 3.jpg... I want to set the names. after I done with the images, I want to clear them.However setting the image to nil doesn't clear the image names , So if I want to pick the same image again I can't set its name because the name is already registered somewhere in app kit framework.

I already found how to clear the cache will update the Question